# Why does convexity of a function required the following

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

What is the significance of the following condition

$$\forall x_1, x_2 \in dom(f) , \forall \theta \in [0, 1], f(\theta x - (1-\theta)y) \leq \theta f(x) + (1-\theta)f(y)$$

and why isn't the condition simply

$$range(f) \text{  is convex} $$

Comment: Try your simpler condition in the one-dimensional case, and you will see that it's much weaker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that one condition is algebraic and one is geometric. both are needed to develop intuition of both kinds.

The correct geometric condition, by the way, is that the epigraph of $f$ be convex, not the range. Consider, e.g. $f(x) = -|x|$ with a perfectly convex range $(-\infty,0]$ (but the function, of course, is concave, not convex).

**EDIT** As for the meaning behind the algebraic intuition, if you assume $f''$ exists, then the convexity condition (your inequality in the question) is equivalent to $f''(x) \ge 0$. The proof can be found [on ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Convex_or_Concave_Function) (see the Corollary there).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you mind elaborate further on the algebraic intuition?

Comment: @user2654176 I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I don't quite understand how the above condition ties into convexity, from what I can see so far it just require the function to be continuous and smooth

Comment: @user2654176 see the edit, this is equivalent to $f''>0$ (assume $f''$ exists).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification